CDK bootstrap and deploy with assume role without admin access
Trust me , I have been struggling with this issue for almost a week now . I have been provided with role which I can assume to provision resources in specific account .
But the point here , the role doesn't have any permissions or policies added to it . When questioned they just told me that I have do define what all permissions needed to be provided to this role so that it can create resources .
Everywhere I see that admin access needs to be provided for bootstrapping which my org is not ready to provide . I don't find any proper document either . Any guidance is really appreciated

Refer to the following issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/21937
